# In Custom page - next_posts_link Not working while previous_posts_link is working

Tags: loop, paginate-links

I have a custom template which has a custom query. I am using this template to create a page (Not a front page) from wordpress. Since the page has multiple posts, I want to put a navigation..... I did look at the multiple forums and posts which explains the problem with naviagations links not showing but in all the cases. Bot the next and previous links are not showing whereas in my case only the next_posts_link is Not showing while previous_posts_link is working fine.

printing the page number from paged works fine and browsing also works fine, but the links are not displayed as expected.

Here is my code and query

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
echo 'paged ' . $paged; 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => CUSTOM_POST_TYPE,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'meta_key' => 'type',
    'meta_value' => 'something',
);

$printposts = new WP_Query( $args );

<div class="nav-previous "><?php previous_posts_link( ' Newer posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next "><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts »' ); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here

- The use of `'no_found_rows' => true` is incorrect. `no_found_rows` is meant for queries that will **not** be paginated. `'no_found_rows' => true` is passed by `get_posts` to `WP_Query` to legally "break" pagination, that is why `get_posts` cannot be paginated as normal.

  What is really happening here is, by default is, when you query the db for posts with `WP_Query`, `WP_Query` runs through the whole db and look for all posts matching the query parameters. This happens with the main query and custom queries. So, if you need 5 posts per page, your query will return 5 posts, but the complete db was checked for all posts matching the query and that amount is returned and stored into the `$found_posts` property of the query object. The amount of posts found matching the query is used to calculate (internally) the `$max_num_pages` property which is integral in calculating pagination in paginated queries. `$max_num_pages` is what will tell the pagination function how many pages of posts there will be (*you can check the amount of pages there will be in your query with `echo $printposts->max_num_pages`*) and then display the links accordingly.

  With `no_found_rows` set to `true`, the above process is skipped. `WP_Query` will now just look for the first 5 posts that matches the query, halt/stop execution and returns the 5 posts. The process of counting all posts in the db to establish all posts matching the specific query is skipped. So, as I said, you are now legally breaking pagination as pagination will not work on such a query. This is done to save on resources when a non paginated query is run. It make such a query faster and save on the amount of time that the query spends (unnecessary) in the db.

  As you need to paginate your query, you need to remove `'no_found_rows' => true`
- The `next_posts_link()` function is set to the amount of pages according to the main query object. On page templates, there wil only be one page ever, so your links will never work just on default. To make this work, you need to set `next_posts_link()` to the `$max_num_pages` property of your custom query. This is real easy, as the second parameter of `next_posts_link()` accepts a custom set of amount of pages. So all you need to do is to pass `$printposts->max_num_pages` as second parameter like this

  ```
  <div class="nav-next "><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts »', $printposts->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
  ```

Just one extra note, `suppress_filters` are by default set to false which means that the `posts_*` filters can influence and modify the query as needed. I usually set this parameter to `true` for custom queries, then I know I am save and no custom filters can interfere with my custom query

Comment: I am also looking to add pagination scrolling so when a user reaches the end of the page. the next set if posts are loaded. Do you think i will need to change anything in the query for that ? Tried few plugins like 'WP EasyScroll Posts' and more with proper CSS selectors but no results.

Comment: Some infinite scroll plugins like the one that comes with jetpack don't work with custom queries, only the main query. I'm not fimiliar with infinite scroll as I have never used it before, but I suspect an ajax option will do here. Have a look at [this google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=ms-rim&hl=en&q=ajax%20infinite%20scroll%20custom%20queries&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&channel=browser)